# Elastislide with vertical Nav

Tags: jquery

Find this nice free gallery carousel called Elastislide

but the code to display the enlarged pic is only available on Demo-4.
http://tympanus.net/Development/Elastislide/index4.html

Where can I found the code to make it work with the vertical carousel?
http://tympanus.net/Development/Elastislide/index2.html

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $( '#carousel' ).elastislide( {
         orientation : 'vertical'  
    } );
</script>
```